# NSIS hide its window?

Tags: windows, nsis

How do I hide the installer itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `HideWindow` option, see the [documentation](http://www.nullsoft.com/free/nsis/makensis.htm#HideWindow).

```
... Macro Section above ...

HideWindow

... Sections/Functions below ...
```